# MvvmCross ViewModel Start method async behavior clarification

Tags: async-await, mvvmcross

In my ViewModel I load data in (overrided) `Start` method, like so:

```
    public override async void Start()
    {
        base.Start();

        await ProcessItems();
        // or the following (no difference for Start method behavior)
        await ProcessItems().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

However, it doesn't look like the await/async logic actually works with the method (I tested it with Android only, though).
"Doesn't work" means that right after calling my awaitable ProcessItems all the rest of ViewModel pipeline is called (like `Initialize`, `ViewCreated`, `ViewAppearing` etc.) **before the awaitable method actually finished work**.
Which brings up some further issues as the rest of methods expect the data initialization already finished.

So, what should I take into consideration here and how handle this situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calling code can't await `Start` because it is returning `void`. Any exceptions being thrown in there are being swallowed. If the method returned `Task` or `Task<T>` then this would work as you expect. You pretty much never want to use `async void` except in an event handler. There is an [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) going further into detail as to why `async void` should be avoided.

This problem is fixed in MvvmCross 5 and later where you would do this same kind of initialization in  `Task Initialize` method in place of this `void Start` method.

Answer (score 2):

Since MvvmCross 5.0 there is a new lifecycle. https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/viewmodel-lifecycle#initialize 
Please use `Initialize` for your stuff instead of `Start`.

> 3. Initialize: All heavy work should be run here. This method returns a Task, which means you can mark it as async and use await safely. If this method fails, the Navigate call that you are probably awaiting will fail, so you might want to catch that exception.

```cs
public async Task Initialize()
{
    await base.Initialize();

    await ProcessItems();
}
```